# Why was the nose cone on the Space Shuttle's external tank pointy?

Tags: space-shuttle, design, aerodynamics, external-tank

*Inspired by comments under this [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/39173/6944) to this question 
[Just how pointy does a rocket's nosecone need to be?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/36263/just-how-pointy-does-a-rockets-nosecone-need-to-be) (see also [Why are the nose cones of current spacecraft less pointy?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/13571/why-are-the-nose-cones-of-current-spacecraft-less-pointy))*

Why was the External Tank's nose cone pointy?

[image]

(Image source: https://steemitimages.com/DQmXscrjPZRpFwkAdvTvUHkL1Bb9csesUpqzBz2JA8Q8JZk/image.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The original External Tank nose cone design was indeed blunt - almost like a fireplug, as seen in this 1975 concept art.

[image]

[Image source - lost in the mists of time to me, but NASA somewhere]

However, [wind tunnel testing](https://www.arnold.af.mil/Portals/49/documents/60th/AFD-110927-014.pdf?ver=2016-06-14-082850-667) at the Arnold Engineering Development Center revealed that this configuration caused unsteady aerodynamic buffeting at some conditions. A bi-conic spike design was conceived and further wind tunnel testing showed that it eliminated the problem.

The nose cone served several functions besides its aerodynamic one.

- The "flared" portion of the nose cone covered the area where the [GO2
  pressurization line and the cable tray](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20080018471.pdf)  entered the tip of the O2
  tank.

[image]

[Cropped from https://www.nasa.gov/centers/marshallimages/content/149235main_IMG_2558_3072x2048.jpg ]

- It also covered the LO2 vent/relief valve and provided vent exits for
  gases boiled off from the LO2 tank, which were subsequently carried
  off by the "beanie cap" umbilical arm.

[image]

[Image Source https://contactsam.files.wordpress.com/2014/11/vent_arm_141113_2.jpg ]

- Finally, the aluminum spike at the tip [acted as a lightning rod](https://science.ksc.nasa.gov/shuttle/technology/sts-newsref/et.html).
  The large lower cone was made of composite material.

Comment: The concept art is interesting.  No hatches for the ejection seats.

Comment: @DrSheldon it was the least wonky one I could find. The others had OMS pods extending onto the payload bay doors, antennas sticking out of the nose cone, etc. etc. ...Artistic license....  The first link in the answer shows a (sadly blurry) picture of the wind tunnel model with the fireplug on the front.