# Is this egg-shaped nose cone a good, aerodynamic design?

Tags: rockets, aerodynamics

So Jeff Bezos has recently travelled to space aboard an Amazon-funded rocket, which has an unusual, egg-shaped nose.

[image: Bezos' rocket, with egg-shaped nose]

However, just about every other rocket I've seen has more of a cone-shaped nose, coming to more of a point. Here's an example, the Saturn V rocket:

[image: Saturn V rocket with cone-shaped nose]

I'd always assumed that the more straight-edged cone-shaped nose had been found to have the most favourable aerodynamics for a rocket to take flight.

Has this assumption now been proven wrong and an egg-shape offers less air resistance? or is there some other reason for this choice of design?

Comment: Are your examples meant to show that most rockets have cone shaped tips? The falcon rocket picture looks egg shaped at the top. The orbiter part of the space shuttle doesn't have a tip which comes to a sharp point. The solid boosters appear to have spherical nose tip. The examples, IMO, show the variety in the tips.

Comment: Amazon funded???

Comment: @user40799 According to Jeff Bezos, yes. https://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/gadgets-and-tech/jeff-bezos-amazon-workers-space-flight-b1887468.html

Comment: He doesn't say it was Amazon funded.

Comment: @user40799 This is getting off-topic, but what part of  Bezo's statement "I also want to thank every Amazon employee and every Amazon customer because you guys paid for all of this" did you not understand?

Comment: @DavidHammen - Bezos taking his assets based on founding Amazon and using them for his space company is different from Amazon paying directly. ]

Comment: by that reasoning SpaceX is ebay funded. @DavidHammen

Comment: related answer & question : [Why/when is the blunt nose better?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/24414/why-when-is-the-blunt-nose-better)

Comment: FWIW: A conical surface has zero [Gaussian curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature). That makes it easy to fabricate cone shapes from flat material such as sheet aluminum. Curved surfaces like the dome-shaped nose of the New Shepard capsule are more expensive. I don't know what the New Shepard is made of, but the _relative_ cost of curved vs. flat surfaces is much less with modern composite materials than it used to be with classic, metal "skin and stringer" airframe designs.

Comment: I was just about to ask the same question.  The modern capsules of Falcon and (especially) New Shepard are noticeably rounder than the cone-shaped 1960's capsules.

Answer (score 26):

1. Rocket noses come in all sorts and sizes. The driving factor is more likely to be functional than purely aerodynamic.
   For example, the shown Saturn V has a pointy nose, because that nose is wearing a pointy Launch Escape System.
   The Falcon 9 fairing nose is a blunted cone.   (no escape system)
   The Falcon 9 hoisting a crew Dragon2 has a mostly-cone with a rounded nose. (escape system mounted on the sides, which is part of why it's not a smooth cone shape)
   The Soyuz nose is pointy, because like the Saturn V it has a very pointy launch escape system.
   In the case of BO's New Shepard, it has a launch escape system, but the motor is affixed to the capsule bottom, between it and the rocket body. Thus it does not affect the shape of the nose.
2. If you are asking what shape is most aerodynamic, it would be a very sharp cone with a pointy tip. This shape is ok at subsonic speeds, and very superior at super->hypersonic speeds. Superior for drag, that is. It also heat up much more, and thus requires really fancy materials at the sort of speed rockets reach while still in real atmosphere.
   However, for a rocket mass is more important. The very small aerodynamic advantage a pointy tip confers is outweighed by the mass saving benefit of a blunted cone. That shape has much smaller surface area *and* is a naturally stronger shape, thus can be built using lighter materials.

Yes, BO's New Shepard's nose is quite sufficiently aerodynamic. It is also a very good shape to facilitate reentry, house the parachutes, and give the passengers a decent window view. As with most engineering designs, it is the balance of all the requirements that leads to a suitable compromise solution.
Remember also that the New Shepard does not get to go very fast, it's top speed on the way up is only about 1000m/s, or mach 2.9-ish. Actual orbital rockets reach three times that speed in atmosphere on the way up, and 8 times that speed coming down.

What is not so aerodynamic is that ridge/ledge under the tip, where it joins the shaft. But this is required for the separation of the booster, and subsequent return of both pieces.

**Supplemental info, specially added for jamesqf**

THIS is a symmetrical aerofoil shape. Also known as "streamlined body"
(Airflow from the right to left.  )
It is very aerodynamic. CD as low as 0.04
[image: symmetric aerofoil, snatched from https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/39146/how-do-symmetrical-airfoils-generate-lift]

---

THIS is the shape of a raindrop.
It is very non-aerodynamic, CD from 0.5 (very small droplets, almost spherical, image B below) up to 1.45. Yes, you read that right. One point four five, for a large raindrop about to break up under its own aero drag, image E below.
(Airflow from bottom to top)
[image: Acual shapes of raindrops as function of size, from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drop_(liquid)]

---

And the aerodynamic shape of the New Shepard is roughly a match for the rightmost of these shape, called the "bullet", which is basically a hemisphere on top of a long cylinder.
It is a pretty good but not perfect aerodynamic shape,
with a subsonic coefficient of drag of about 0.3 (due to the discontinuity leading to the rocket body)

(Airflow from left to right in this image)

[image: Shape effect on subsonic air drag, from https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/shaped.html]

Comment: Re #2, a pointy cone with a sharp tip is quite un-aerodynamic at subsonic speeds.  In fact, it would be more aerodynamic if you turned it around :-)  A raindrop is most aerodynamic, if you don't consider the effects of all that expanding gas coming out of the  tail.  And with rockets like the Saturn V, the taper is because of the different size of the stages, not aerodynamic considerations.  (That is, there's a height/diameter ratio that minimizes weight, which is why soda cans are the shape they are.)  Bezos' rocket appears to have only a single stage.

Comment: @jamesqf "A raindrop is most aerodynamic" is false. A raindrop is an incredibly high drag object. Are you maybe forgetting that a falling raindrop looks like a beanbag that uncle albert is sitting on?

Comment: Actual shape of raindrops: https://www.scienceabc.com/pure-sciences/shape-falling-raindrop-pressure-sphere-surface-tension-hydrostatics-aerodynamics-gravity-myth.html or for image only https://www.scienceabc.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/2000px-Raindrops_sizes.svg_.jpg

Comment: @jamesqf additionally, "a pointy cone with a sharp tip is quite un-aerodynamic at subsonic speeds. In fact, it would be **more aerodynamic if you turned it around**" is *very* false. Flat-based pointy cone with nose into the wind has CD of 0.34, same cone turned around has CD of 1.14

Comment: The trailing side does not follow traditional aerodynamics because of the rocket exhaust.

Comment: You're all really missing the point here, which is that aerodynamics on launch is fr from the primary consideration for shape.  If you take for instance the Saturn V, the tip is pointy because that's the way they built the launch escape system.  Then the Apollo CM is the size and shape it is because it had to hold three astronauts and have a re-entry heat shield.  The SM/LM package fits nicely behind it.  Then you have three stages that are basically soda can shapes, because that's how you minimize structure weight while maximizing propellant load.

Comment: @jamesqf Isn't that *exactly* what my answer says in the first place? Which point you tied to muddy by making multiple false statements in comments?

Comment: @PcMan: No, that is not what your answer says, though it might be what you meant it to say. And I made no false statements, though some might (and have!)quibble about details.  But let me say it again: as a design factor, aerodynamics is well behind quite a number of other considerations.

Comment: @jamesqf FALSE STATEMENT THE FIRST "A raindrop is most aerodynamic". FALSE STATEMENT THE SECOND "a pointy cone with a sharp tip is quite un-aerodynamic at subsonic speeds. In fact, it would be more aerodynamic if you turned it around".

Comment: @PcMan: The classic raindrop shape IS the most aerodynamic, at subsonic speeds.  If you don't believe me, ask NASA: https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/shaped.html  Or look at the shape of anything that is designed to minimize drag.

Comment: I've strongly criticized RonJohn's answer because it was overly reliant on imagery and because that user did not replace the `enter image description here` with something more meaningful. It would help your answer if you replaced that default with something more meaningful.

Comment: The raindrop image and a discussion of it might make for a good answer to [What are typical ranges of rainfall drop sizes, speeds, and areal or volume densities?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/13727/6031) in Earth Science SE.

Answer (score 14):

> I'd always assumed that the more straight-edged cone-shaped nose had been found to have the most favourable aerodynamics for a rocket to take flight.

There's a key problem with sharp-nosed tips: They have a tendency to melt at high speeds. The Concorde only flew at Mach 2, and it's tip heated to 127 °C. This heating is a huge problem for hypersonic aircraft. This heating around sharp edges was part of why the Space Shuttle Columbia experienced its disastrous failure.

Modern launch vehicles don't have the pointy tips that the Saturn V and other early launch vehicles had. The pointy tip doesn't buy much with regard to aerodynamic efficiency, and it adds lots of risk.

Answer (score 2):

In Joe Rogan's podcast #1609, talking with Elon Musk, Elon mentioned it makes no difference when it comes to rockets. It is arguable worse to be pointy.

As Antzi mentions, this is because of the speeds involved, and the issues with hypersonic flows.

Comment: In subsonic flows, the pointiness serves to move the air around. In hypersonic flows this can’t happen so it doesn’t matter much. You are right

Comment: I feel like the answer quite clearly answers the asked question, with references. And also adds the more indepth pointer to Antzi's post. Most answers were elaborate, which is in some cases wanted, but not always.

Answer (score -2):

Boeing and SpaceX also use blunt nose cones (as demonstrated in these images), and not just for human capsules.  Thus, unless all these engineers are incompetent, blunt cones must be a good idea.

[image]
[image]

Comment: A good idea, yes, but is it good because of aerodynamics, or other considerations?

Comment: @jamesqf *aerodynamic* means "of or having a shape which reduces the drag from air moving past", and a smooth, rounded surface certainly helps the air flow by.  The Space Shuttle has a rounded nose, Boeing airliners have rounded noses, and the leading edges of *most* wings are rounded, so that "roundness" **must** be a good, all-purpose aerodynamic shape; otherwise it wouldn't be used so much.  (At some point, the amount of anecdotes piles up so high that "argument from anecdote" morphs into "evidence of truth".)

Comment: The tip of the ascent stack for shuttle was extremely pointy. https://space.stackexchange.com/q/39183/6944

Comment: @OrganicMarble very interesting.  However, I was referring to the Space Shuttle itself.  https://inteng-storage.s3.amazonaws.com/images/uploads/sizes/space-shuttle-1_resize_md.jpg

Comment: Downvoted for an utter lack of accessibility.

Comment: @DavidHammen what does "lack of **accessibility**" mean in this context?

Comment: @RonJohn The answer excessively relies on imagery, and you have not placed any description of those images as alt text.

Comment: @DavidHammen why is alt-text so vital?

Comment: @RonJohn Alt text can make an image-based answer comprehensible to those who are visually impaired. As is, this answer is useless to those who are visually impaired. Keep in mind the phrase "a good picture is worth 1000 words". This is not the case for the visually impaired. A nice description is essential. It doesn't have to be 1000 words long, but it is essential.

Comment: I'm picking on you because this answer is one of the least accessible answers I've seen. You are not the only one who I've picked on for lack of accessibility. Accessibility is a touchy issue for me. I was exposed to the problem because I've had the privilege of working on multiple projects with a brilliant NASA mathematician who is totally blind. He's employed because he's brilliant. More than half of the visually impaired are not employed, and the problem is getting worse because of a growing over-reliance on imagery on the internet.

Comment: @DavidHammen I hovered my mouse over every other image in teh question, and all the other answers, but saw no alt text.

Comment: @RonJohn [Why should I enter image description?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304115) A halfway decent screen reader will access the image description.

Comment: @DavidHammen have you down-voted the question, and all the other answers for not having alt-text?  If not, you're a hypocrite.

Comment: @RonJohn Though it's primarily about text, you can check the discussions, answers and comment at [Shall we make it explicit site policy that screenshots of text ≠ readable text?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1824/12102) Though it wasn't pointed out very diplomatically, we really do try to make sure that whenever possible, and to the extent possible, our posts contain all the key information as text so that they retain their value, utility and readability both to folks using screen readers and to search engines for indexing and *findability* for future readers.

Comment: Is it possible to add a bit more text explaining what it is that the images show and what it is about them that  constitutes an answer? *Thanks!*

Comment: @uhoh I wait for you also to make these same "images must have alt text" comments in the other answers.

Comment: @RonJohn I have tried to do just that. Every single one? That's not possible. I still have a job. But I do try to hit the worst ones that I do see.

Comment: @DavidHammen every single answer in this question (and the question itself) would show that you're not a hypocrite.

Comment: @RonJohn I've made [almost 18,000 comments](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/12102/uhoh?tab=activity&sort=comments) on this site, and I'm 100% certain that I've left many, many similar comments over the past 5+ years. You're not being singled-out for criticism. Instead I think your answer has value and folks are simply encouraging you to improve it and not rely on pictures to speak for themselves.

Comment: @RonJohn This is one of the most inaccessible answers I've come across. It might well be the most inaccessible answer I've ever come across. Answers are supposed to be of higher quality than are questions, so I am more judgmental with regard to answers. The question was asked by a newbie, so I gave that newbie a break.

Comment: @DavidHammen tell me honestly what's so **inaccessible** about "Boeing and SpaceX also use blunt nose cones (as demonstrated in these images), and not just for human capsules. Thus, unless all these engineers are incompetent, blunt cones must be a good idea."  I can live with you thinking it's a poor answer, but to call it inaccessible is nonsense.

Comment: All that you have to do for me to reverse my downvote is to replace the default `enter image description here` with descriptions of the imagery. **It's not that hard.** Anyhow, I'm done.

Comment: Accessibility aside, "Thus, unless all these engineers are incompetent, blunt cones must be a good idea." is a terrible answer. You should explain *why* blunt cones are ok.  Some rockets have sharp nosecones, and presumably their engineers are equally competent.