# Shape of satellite launch vehicle

Tags: rockets, launch-vehicle, aerodynamics, fairings

I was watching videos on YouTube, and I came across a fact that satellite launch vehicle has shape like a nose or you can ogive shape and I search on Google related to that, and I found that it prevent from extreme dynamic pressure, my question how this ogive shape help to prevent the extreme pressure?  and secondly what If we use pencil type type rocket to launch our satellite in space?

Comment: See which one these answers your question: [Why are the nose cones of current spacecraft less pointy?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/13571/32757), [Just how pointy does a rocket's nosecone need to be?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36263/32757) - If neither answers your question then add more details to your question. Also have a look at the tag [tag:aerodynamics] for more related questions.

Comment: Non of them! How ogive shape help!

Answer (score 2):

You want your rocket to have the least aerodynamic drag (other term for "dynamic pressure" in this context) and as a result fluid dynamics give you an ogive shape as the optimal shape, as seen here:

https://www.jvejournals.com/article/16142

Comment: That paper says the ogive is best for subsonic Mach numbers. Is that why it's used for launch vehicles?

Comment: `-1` temporarily until you can add a bit more explanation into your answer. This is better than [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/36118/could-two-satellites-in-the-same-orbit-but-phased-differently-be-tethered-in-a/41779#comment136490_41779) but it still depends on the link working to be of value and requires everyone go off-site to get it.

Comment: my offer to reverse is still there :-)